# Need better way to add HTML below each photo

Tags: jquery

I'm adding a title and description after each photo in an unordered list (li), and using a combination of jQuery/JSON, the flickr API and a lightbox.  Everything is working, but I know one piece of my code is wrong:

```
.add(
    $("<p>" + item.title + "</p><p>" + item.description._content + "</p>")
)
```

Again, it works, but I know it's wrong.  What is the proper way?  I've tried everything I can think of, but only the code I've typed above works.  What I really want is this, inserted following each photo:

```
<p class="title">item.title</p>
<p class="description">item.description._content</p>
```

Comment: Please edit your title into something more descriptive, so that this question can be found by people with the same problem in the future.

Comment: The world's easiest jQuery question is `what is the full form of jQuery` and guess the answer :P It's jQuery :)

Comment: Modified title to match subject matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the question, but try this...

```
$("<p class='title'>" + item.title + "</p><p class='description'>" + item.description._content + "</p>");
```

And the method is `.after()`, I think.

Comment: You're right about 'title' instead of "title".  I'm still thinking that just dropping in + item.tltle is the wrong way to insert it, but maybe not?  I'm just learning jQuery.

Comment: Hhmmm...  I guess maybe my code wasn't as bad as I thought.  You're right about how to add a class (thanks!), but you didn't correct the part of the code that I assumed was wrong.  I wonder if that means it's ok to add content in jQuery the way I did: `+ item.title +`

Comment: Webars, I don't disagree at all :)  ...but I'm also trying to learn, so I'd like to learn the proper way in hopes of not starting out with bad habits.

Comment: Your syntax is correct. If you are not sure about strings operations, read this article http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html There're much examples.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe append?

```
.after("<p>" + item.title + "</p><p>" + item.description._content + "</p>");
```

EDIT: My bad, it's .after.

Comment: Sorry for the original title.  I figured this one was so easy that someone would answer it in seconds.  (I'm new here)

Comment: It's interesting that in all three answers, people have said to use .after instead of .add  ...but when I use .after, it doesn't work in some variants of IE.  When I use .add, it does work.  But I agree that it seems like .after is the proper way.  I wonder why it doesn't work with .after in IE?  I hate IE!

Answer (score 1):

Use `.after()`:

```
$('your selector for photo elements').after(
    $("<p>" + item.title + "</p><p>" + item.description._content + "</p>")
)
```

Comment: I originally used .after but it didn't work in IE.  When I switched it to .add it worked fine.  My question is really about this line, which I assume is poorly coded:

`$("<p>" + item.title + "</p><p>" + item.description._content + "</p>")`